# Dynamically Adding Object properties as false value when they are not available in the API Output not working?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, google-analytics-4

**Overview:**
I am pulling user funnel data from the GA4 Data API. User Funnel comprises of events such as `view_item`, `add_to_cart`,`begin_checkout`, and `purchase`

I am trying to find out which step of the funnel is missing from the API when data is pulled. The below API output is pulled for 4 steps i.e. `view_item`, `add_to_cart`,`begin_checkout`, and `purchase`, but the output result does not have `purchase` step. This means the user hasn't configured the purchase event yet. My objective is to add the purchase value as false as shown below. Once I get the expected result, I can paste this data into my Google sheet via Appscript.

**API Output from GA4 Account**

In the below code, you will see that all events are being populated except `purchase`.

```
var data = [{
      dimensionValues : [{
        value : 'view_item'
      }],
      metricValues : [{
        value : 175029
      }]
    }, {
      dimensionValues : [{
        value : 'add_to_cart'
      }],
      metricValues : [{
        value : 10049
      }]
    }, {
      metricValues : [{
        value : 6326
      }],
      dimensionValues : [{
        value : 'begin_checkout'
      }]
    } 
  
  ]
```

**Objective**

If event data is not available such as `purchase`, then I want to add this as a false value.

**Expected Result**

```
{
  add_to_cart: 10049,
  begin_checkout: 6326,
  view_item: 175029
  purchase: false
}
```

**This is what I have done so far**

```
var eventArray1 = [];

for (var item in data1) {
      var dimensions = data1[item].dimensionValues;
      for (var i = 0; i < dimensions.length; i++) {
        eventArray1.push([dimensions[i].value, data1[item].metricValues[0].value]);
      }

    }


const obj = Object.fromEntries(eventArray1);

const viewItem = obj.view_item !== undefined;    
const addToCart = obj.add_to_cart !== undefined;
const beginCheckout = obj.begin_checkout !== undefined;
const p = obj.purchase !== undefined;

if (viewItem === false || addToCart === false || beginCheckout === false || p === false) {

obj.view_item = viewItem
obj.add_to_cart = addToCart
obj.begin_checkout = beginCheckout
obj.purchase = p

} else  {}

console.log(obj)
```

**Console Log**

```
{
  add_to_cart: true,
  begin_checkout: true,
  purchase: false,
  view_item: true
}
```

How can I get the expected results as shown above? I would like to add the missing events dynamically to the object. Missing purchase is an example, view item can also be missing if not configured.

Comment: There are several things about your question that are not clear. What do you mean by "missing events"?  Why does `data` contain properties/keys that have arrays of just a single object as the key values instead of just an object as the key value? Where does the data in the `data` variable come from? How would we know that `purchase` is supposed to be there? What does your question title have to do with the text of your question?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Data is being pulled from GA4 Data API. I am pulling event data for user funnel or user journey starting from view item to purchase. Now if the user hasn't configured these events, the event data can't be pulled hence it will be missing from the API output. I am trying to find which event is missing from the funnel. It could be view item, add to cart or begin checkout or purchase. In the above code purchase event is missing. I am saving the api output into data variable.

Comment: I have revised my question. Hopefully, it should be clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the expected output with the below logic.

```
  const data = [
    { dimensionValues: [{ value: "view_item" }], metricValues: [{ value: 175029 }] },
    { dimensionValues: [{ value: "add_to_cart" }], metricValues: [{ value: 10049 }] },
    { metricValues: [{ value: 6326 }], dimensionValues: [{ value: "begin_checkout" }] }
  ];

  const allEvents = ["view_item", "add_to_cart", "begin_checkout", "purchase"];

  const eventArray = data.flatMap((item) =>
    item.dimensionValues.map(({ value }) => [value, item.metricValues[0].value])
  );

  const expectedOutput = Object.fromEntries(eventArray);

  allEvents.forEach((event) => (expectedOutput[event] ??= false));

  console.log(expectedOutput);
```